# Invalid Object Syntax in API Documentation

Tags: javascript, react-native, connectycube

I am following the ConnectyCube API [documentation](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/authentication-and-users) and it tells me to format an object like this when using Firebase credentials:

```
 const userCredentials = {
                      provider: 'firebase_phone',
                      firebase_phone[project_id]: projectId,
                      firebase_phone[access_token]: idToken,
                    };
```

Of course the app won't compile because you can't use square brackets like this, it throws a linting error.

I have tried getting rid of it but it doesn't work, what are they trying to tell me to do?

Comment: `const userCredentials = {}; userCredentials[firebase_phone[project_id]] = projectId`

Comment: Thanks, gives me `firebase_phone is not defined`

Comment: Looks like a clear case for their [support](https://connectycube.com/contact/). They could have meant anything by that, from `projectId: firebase_phone.project_id` to `"firebase_phone[project_id]": projectId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed - must be written like this:

```
provider: 'firebase_phone',
                      'firebase_phone[project_id]': "xxxxxxxxxx",
                      'firebase_phone[access_token]': idToken,
```

Comment: This one is updated https://developers.connectycube.com/js/authentication-and-users?id=authentication-via-phone-number